# Запись класса в файл

Tags: java

Какой класс позволяет сделать запись (и чтение) класса в файл. В С/С++ есть для таких целей `fwrite` и `fread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется сериализацией (и не только в Java). В Java это доведено до абсолюта. Вкратце механизм такой:

1. Берем класс который хотим сериализовать
2. Реализуем интерфейс `Serializable` (по сути только декларируем, поскольку это специальный интерфейс без методов)
3. Поля, которые не надо сохранять декларируем как `transient`
4. Далее берем объект и тупо пишем в файл методом `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`
5. Читаем в обратном порядке (более-менее)

Есть и более хитрые способы сериализации через [JSon](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) или XML или еще чего похлеще. Все эти способы роднит использование рефлексии. Например в популярной гугловской библиотеке [GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) сериализация JSon пишется примерно так:

```
String s=new GSon().toJson(myObject);
```

В итоге получается строка JSon, которую уже можно пихать куда угодно: в файл, сеть и проч. Обратно вытаскиваем объект так:

```
myObject=new Gson().fromJson(s, MyClass.class);
```

В общем подходов много. Берите да пользуйтесь!

Comment: @Barmaley, отличный ответ !

Вот только, что-то мне подсказывает (видимо упоминание fwrite()), что ТС пока не нужна сериализация, а нужны классы java.io.FileWriter, java.io.FileOutputStream и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Только читать/писать все таки объекты нужно, а не классы)
[например тут](http://oxygame.blogspot.com/2010/11/java.html)